# What happens with GETS command if input buffer overflow before any newline character?

Tags: tcl

Assume using the construct: `while {[gets $id line]>0} {...}`. Now what if the single line size is greater than input buffer size?

Comment: Maybe consider using **read** instead of **gets** and specify the number of characters you want to read at one time.

Comment: It's been a while for me since I last did some Tcl coding.. but it may be possible to put the gets into a [catch { [gets $id line] } result] } { handle the error somehow } (??)

Comment: I suspect that would have to be a really, really long line.

Comment: I believe that gets will read up to the amount of memory you have. @DonalFellows can you confirm?

Comment: yes, `gets` seems to continu reading as long as memory is available. Same as when turning off buffering using `-buffersize 0`.

Comment: I believe everything here is answered correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Tcl will buffer the data when no newline is received as long as memory is available, and panic when there isn't. As this could be used for a DoS attack, [TIP #287](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tips/doc/trunk/tip/287.md) introduced the `chan pending` command. This command can be used to take action when the buffered data exceeds a limit.

Note: `chan pending` can only help when used with non-blocking channels.

Comment: This is exactly right. If you want to limit memory used by incoming buffers, you _must_ use nonblocking I/O. Luckily, Tcl is exceptionally good at it. The point to check the buffer size is when `chan blocked`/`fblocked` returns true (after a `gets` soft fail).